# How do to a generic rewrite in Liftweb?

Tags: scala, lift

I want to rewrite urls in generic ways. For example I have a list of urls in a CSV file, read them them and want to rewrite the URL in Liftweb.

e.g. the file contains

> buy-electronics/products/:id
>
> cheap-phones/products/:id

and I want to rewrite those to

> /products?id=[id from path]

I've only found examples with case matching in Liftweb. With case matching it would look something like:

```
case RewriteRequest(
  ParsePath("buy-electronics" :: "products" :: id :: Nil), _, _, _), _, _) => {
        RewriteResponse(
          List("products"), Map("id" -> id)
        )
  }
```

but I have found nothing on how to add rewriting rules in a generic way. Any ideas beside generating Scala code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern matching guards to achieve this.

In a simplified example, assuming the first part of the path (buy-electronics, cheap-phones) is the only thing that actually changes (maybe that even does the trick in your case), you could add a guard that checks whether it is contained in the list you read from the CSV file.

```
// actually read from CSV
val prefixes = Seq("buy-electronics", "cheap-phones")

case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(prefix :: "products" :: id :: Nil), _, _, _), _, _)
  if (prefixes contains prefix) => 
    RewriteResponse(List("products"), Map("id" -> id))
```

If you need more complex structures to be possible, you can bind the whole path in a variable (`... ParsePath(path), _, ...`) and check whether that value matches some of the lines in your list, again in the guard expression.

Comment: Thanks @doertsch Might be that one prefix is enough. How would one proceed after the match to ParsePath? With "if (test something with path) => RewriteResponse(...) ?

Comment: @Stephan In the more complex case, you'll need some custom logic to extract the ID (or whatever dynamic parts the path contains), as the `path` value is now all you have in the body of that case. This extraction will probably share large parts of code with the predicate that you use to test whether the path matches one of your alternatives. This depends on how complex you want it to be, of course; for example, if you're always just looking for the id and it is always the last section of the URL, you can simply use `RewriteResponse(List("products"), Map("id" -> path.last))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both answers helped